# Is there any alternative to the Mediator pattern with Collegue "idle"?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, mediator

I have a project in which its activities and functions follows a sequential process, most of the time. But sometimes you need to "go back" your steps and rerun the previous functions.

I made a state diagram to see how complex it would be.

The first approach I thought was applying the State pattern but the number of states did not seem feasible. Then "I separated" and classified it functions in 6 processes. A grades traits each process what I imagined something like this:

```
TProcessXXX = class(TProcess)
private
{* atributos privados, etc.. *}
public
{* funciones y actividades *}
procedure DoActivity1;
procedure DoActivity2;
{* ... *}
function DoActivityN: TResultProcess;
end;
```

Most of the activities they of the each Process operate on the same class that encapsulates the data structure needed. And my intention is that each Process can notify has ended for another process then the next job.

The design I've seen is the Mediator pattern, and have a class that encapsulates the state diagram and "enable" to each process.
To coordinate among themselves I considered add methods to communicate with the coordinator/mediator class. Including:

```
function TProcess.RequestPermission: boolean;

procedure TProcess.NotifyFinishOperation(Result: TResultOperation);
```

In the process I designed them with some independence.

As for being not asking permission for each activity and for some need some redundant sequencing and ask again and again, I applied a "lock" that allows enable them.

```
TProcessXXX.PrepareToWork;
var req: boolean;
begin
    req: = RequestPermission;
    then begin if req
EnableActivitys
Work;
end;
end;
```

So far so good. My doubts began when from the Presentation layer invoke operations processes.
To get permission to invoke I have a indirection from the layer Presentation to the Mediator: Presentation -> TProcessXXX -> Mediator
And then we obtained permission another for each activity: Presentation -> TProcessXXX -> TDataStructure

When a process receives permission, captures for himself using TDataStructure. It takes over until the operation is completed. Meanwhile, other processes are "idle". And from the Presentation layer may be giving you request to operate needlessly.

I considered disabling controls, which is the most straightforward and easy. But then would have to be enabling and disabling all the time.

I ask: What alternatives do you recommend? Is there a pattern to work on the theme of "idle processes"?

---

EDIT:

I have studied alternatives such as Strategy and Visitor but I am not sure if they are the best option. And I admit that perhaps these 3 patterns (Mediator, Strategy, Visitor) do not dominate the 100%.
I forgot to clarify this. My apologies.

I would also add that if I deserve a negative vote, at least be kind enough to post a comment explaining why.

---

EDIT 2:

As recommended, I attached a link to a picture of the state diagram:
[image]

In the diagram you can see that there is a choise. Is designed so that at startup evaluates which was the last state reached and to continue from that point.

In this diagram I have separate activities in five processes: configuration, manage set, training, testing and recognition.

And I added one more, the sixth named initializer, which has the function to initialize the data structure with the data accessed from a database.

Each Process is a Collegue for the Mediator. The Mediator implements this state diagram and decides to process him "permission" to operate.

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted your question but I belive the reason for downvote is that Stack Owerflow is for solving specific coding problems while you are asking about the use of proper design pattern. I belive that asking your question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ would fit more.

Comment: I've seen other questions like this, something old, and has not been given any objections and received replies. Another negative more votes, and that if one puts the good intention. As I watched no trolls in SO walking playing negative voting. Who has power must be controlled.

Comment: Are any of your activities executed concurently (multithreading)?

Comment: No. But a friend from another forum suggested it. I'm considering it.

Comment: If you need to clarify something, please let me know they did.

Comment: Well if you are indeed thinking about implementing multithreading support then I can tell you that the use of Decision Tree pattern alone won't be good enough.

Comment: By the way what do those three red dots on your diagram represent?

Comment: When my friend suggested me to use the wireless told me that the system can gain speed and can be running two things happen simultaneously. How to train and recognize for example. My work should be prototype, but maybe if I do multithreading would much better. I came to think that an alternative design that supports this could be the Pipes and Filters pattern. What other alternative could consider?

Comment: By circles in the diagram see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't best formed so I'm not compleetly sure what are you trying to achieve. But I asume you want to implement some more complex code flow controll which is based on certain conditions.

If my asumption is correct you should check the Decision Tree pattern.

In Decision Tree pattern you have your work divided into multiple smaller steps(which is what yseems you are already trying to implement).

On the end of each step you check specific condition and then decide how to proceed based on that condition (either continue with next step, repeat current step or even jumpt to compleetly different step).

From your SO profile information I see you are computer engineering student so I can tell you that the usage of decision trees is usually discussed during the AI development classes in great depth becouse most complex AI algorithms actually depends on using Decision Tree pattern as it procidea great scalability.

So you might want to check your school books for the section that describes AI development.

Comment: If need be adding something to the description of my problem, I can ask for. I have studied the subject of trees, both in the cathedra of Data Structures and Expert Systems for the use of IA.
Granted it as a pattern I is not familiar. I should clarify that non taught in my studied, I've studied on my own.

Comment: The thing that would help me best to understand what you want to implement is providing that state diagram you mentioned you made to see the complexity of your code.